# FB Singleton Login

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm creating a singleton to access all Facebook methods and I want to handle the Login dialog in this singleton.

I followed the iOS SDK Tutorial on Facebook, but it only allows me to login within application launch and not when a user presses a button.

Whats the alternative to

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

It seems to be the problem, my App isn't switching to the browser or FB App to login.
When I'm implementing the same stuff in AppDelegate it works, but immediatly after Application launch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it like this:

in AppDelegate:

```
-(void)connectToFacebook{
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAPPID andDelegate:self];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];

}

if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:nil];
}
}

// For 4.2+ support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}

- (void)fbDidLogin {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
}
```

And in Singleton:

```
- (id)init {
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
    NBNAppDelegate *delegate = (NBNAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegate connectToFacebook];
    facebook =  delegate.facebook;        
}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you accepted your own solution as working, there is a simple solution to the original question that accomplishes having the login code in the singleton. The only thing you need to put in your app delegate is the openURL (and handleOpenURL for pre 4.2 support). Here's an example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
{
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb%@", facebookAppId]]) {        
        return [[FacebookSingleton sharedFacebook].facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
    }
}
```

Everything else you can put into your singleton (including all your login code), and not have to clutter up your application delegate. Your singleton then implements the FBSessionDelegate code. This sample code assumes that you declare a property on your singleton called "facebook". This is where the Facebook object lives, not in your delegate.

Note: I check the scheme before forwarding the url to Facebook. You only need this if your app has other schemes that it accepts.

If anyone wants the singleton code, leave a message and I can post that as well.